# How to make groupings of lists using {

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to format a webpage to show a set of workouts but group them together in a set like the screenshot below.

[image: Grouping of Workouts]

I know that the right-hand side could be a simple list like `ul` but I'm trying to figure out how to get it formatted like this without using tables. Any HTML or JS methods that I may not know of?

Comment: this can be achieved with a lot of different strats, you can do it with ul/ol/tables/paragraph/span, even with css and so on, just pick one and do it! :)

Comment: One step towards your goal could be to try using `initial-letter` in CSS.
1. [initial-letter on CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/initial-letter/)
2. [initial-letter on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial-letter)

Comment: The browser support for `initial-letter` seems to be very poor though. See [this article](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-letter/) for instance.

Comment: Flexbox helps to easily center the content in the vertical. To “stretch” the `{` to the appropriate height, you could implement it as a (background) image, SVG, border-image.

Answer (score 1):

This is an approach based on [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="counter">3x</div>
    <div class="collection">{</div>
    <div class="items">
        <ul>
            <li>20 x pushups</li>
            <li>30 x KB swings</li>
            <li>10 x pullups</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: colum;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10em;
    width: 25em;
}

.counter {
    font-size: 5em;
}

.collection {
    font-size: 9em;  
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    -webkit-margin-before: 0;
    -webkit-margin-after: 0;  
    -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

.items {  
    font-size: 2em;  
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: colum;
  align-items: center;
  height: 10em;
  width: 25em;
}

.counter {
  font-size: 5em;
}

.collection {
  font-size: 9em;  
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0;  
  -webkit-padding-start: 0;
}

.items {  
  font-size: 2em;  
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="counter">3x</div>
    <div class="collection">{</div>
    <div class="items">
      <ul>
        <li>20 x pushups</li>
        <li>30 x KB swings</li>
        <li>10 x pullups</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/programmerper/pen/PBaZyp